# Format number data with comma and unit in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to format the data on Highchart like `$ 1,000`

I used this setting. The data format will be `1,000`

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

Then, I add unit for yAxis

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    labels: {
        distance: 20,
        format: '$ {value}'
    }
}
```

But, the data format is `$ 1000`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) give the following examples:

> - Two decimal places: `"{point.y:.2f}"`
> - Thousands separator, no decimal places: `{point.y:,.0f}`
> - Thousands separator, one decimal place: `{point.y:,.1f}`

Per the example given, you want to use `'$ {value:,.0f}'`.